# PHP - JSON array to javascript datatable library

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, datatables

I am sending JSON array to my ajax response and trying to print a table with response data using datatable library , on my server side I am using this code

```
$products = array(
array('choc_cake', 'Chocolate Cake', 'scsdsf'),
array('carrot_cake', 'Carrot Cake', 'sdfds'),
array('cheese_cake', 'Cheese Cake', 'dsadas'),
array('banana_bread', 'Banana Bread', 'dasdas')
);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $products , JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

which is producing json like `[ [x,y,z],[x,y,z],[x,y,z] ]` and I am passing the javascript ajax response string to datatable library code which is :

```
var saman = hr.responseText.trim(); 
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: saman,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" }
    ]
} );
```

but this code giving me [this error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4)

Comment: Could you dump the output of `console.log(saman)` after the first line of your example JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want saman to be an array or a string?

If array, please use:

```
var saman = eval(hr.responseText.trim());
```

or it is just a string.

Remember: no matter what php outputs, it is only some text, not any live code so you have to use `eval` to parse it to an array.